# Why Are All List's Being Populated

Tags: c++, regex, list, iterator, istream-iterator

So given the definitions:

```
typedef char Task;

struct Tache {
    char step;
    int duration;
    list<Task> precedentTask;
};
```

I've written an extraction operator for `Tache`:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& lhs, Tache& rhs) {
    string line;

    getline(lhs, line, '\n');

    stringstream ss(line);

    ss >> rhs.step;
    ss.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '(');
    ss >> rhs.duration;
    ss.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ')');

    const regex re("\\s*,\\s*([a-zA-Z])");
    string precedentTasks;

    getline(ss, precedentTasks);

    transform(sregex_token_iterator(cbegin(precedentTasks), cend(precedentTasks), re, 1), sregex_token_iterator(), back_insert_iterator<list<Task>>(rhs.precedentTask), [](const string& i) {
        return i.front();
    });

    return lhs;
}
```

However when I try to use this extraction operator with an `istream_iterator` the `precedentTask` member seems to bleed into the next element. For example, given:

```
stringstream seq("A(3)\nB(4),A\nC(2),A\nE(5),A\nG(3),A\nJ(8),B,H\nH(7),C,E,G\nI(6),G\nF(5),H");

list<Tache> allTaches{ istream_iterator<Tache>(seq), istream_iterator<Tache>() };

for (const auto& i : allTaches) {
    cout << i.step << ' ' << i.duration << ' ';
    copy(cbegin(i.precedentTask), cend(i.precedentTask), ostream_iterator<Task>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/FjPd73)

I am getting:

> A 3 
>   B 4 A 
>   C 2 A A 
>   E 5 A A A 
>   G 3 A A A A 
>   J 8 A A A A B H 
>   H 7 A A A A B H C E G 
>   I 6 A A A A B H C E G G 
>   F 5 A A A A B H C E G G H

Rather than my expected:

> A 3 
>   B 4 A 
>   C 2 A 
>   E 5 A 
>   G 3 A 
>   J 8 B H 
>   H 7 C E G 
>   I 6 G 
>   F 5 H

Am I misusing the `sregex_token_iterator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with regex and everything to do with what `istream_iterator` does under the hood: it only has one `T` element that it will read into when you increment it:

> `istream_iterator& operator++();`
>   3 *Requires*: `in_stream != 0`.
>   4 *Effects*: `*in_stream >> value`.
>   5 *Returns*: `*this`.

Your stream operator is just appending to `rhs.precedentTask`, but it's not necessarily empty to start with. Just clear it first. This isn't an `istream_iterator` problem either, your `operator>>` has to be able to work in this situation too:

```
Tache foo;
while (std::cin >> foo) {
    // ...
}
```

If all you're doing is *appending*, then every subsequent `Tache` after the first one will be wrong. You are completely responsible for initializing all of the members of the object and you should make no assumptions about their previous values.

---

I'd recommend substituting `transform()` for just a loop:

```
sregex_token_iterator it(cbegin(precedentTasks), cend(precedentTasks), re, 1), end;
for (; it != end; ++it) {
    rhs.precedentTask.push_back(it->front());
}
```

or wrapping that in a range:

```
for (std::string match : sregex_matches(precedentTasks, re, 1)) {
    rhs.precedentTask.push_back(match.front());
}
```

Comment: Ugh... clearing it worked, but I have absolutely no explanation as to why. `rhs.precedentTask`. How could `precedentTask` *not* be working with an empty element? You're saying that if I only wrote my extraction operator to extract some of the members of an object I may well get non-zero initialized members x.x

Comment: @JonathanMee Elaborated a bit on the answer. And yes, of course.

Comment: I was hoping for a bit more detail on possible workarounds, so I have opened a linked question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37682156/2642059